# Filtered Row Count

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I wish to find the row count of a filtered column, so I wrote VBA code as

```
FilteredRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
```

But FilteredRowCount always return value of 1, what would cause this?

Comment: `Rows.Count` will only return the row count of the first *area*.... see the [`Range.Rows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rows) documentation.

Comment: @BigBen Ahhh.... This is the reason it always returns value 1, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each rng In rngDB.Areas
        r = r + rng.Rows.Count
    Next rng
    MsgBox r

End Sub
```