# How to select rows only from range with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to copy a filtered data from table and paste it in another workbook. This process works so far, but the row count of the copied data is more than the actual row count of the range. It appears to be counting the rows for each columns in the copied filtered table because when I paste the values I also see additional empty rows.

I tried `.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count` but gave me error. Something about "The range won't work because it doesn't align with existing table..."

```
 'Filter the data based on the field and criteria
    With SourceListObject
        If Not Id = "" Then
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Id
        End If
        
        'Get the total visible cell count after filtering
        SourceDataRowsCount = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

    End With
    
    
    'Copy the filtered data to the table
    With DestListObject
        'Get the count of the rows in the table (starts with 2 empty rows - need to figure out a way to either
        'have no row and add to the table or delete the rows after adding values to the rows
        'Then set the size of the range based on the source range count
        TargetDataRowsCount = .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        .Resize .Range.Resize(SourceDataRowsCount, .Range.Columns.Count)
        
        'Paste the values in the first row
        SourceListObject.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        
    End With
    
    
    'Clear the filter
    With SourceListObject
    
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
        
    End With
```

I see empty rows like this one. This is from made up data:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400102/filtered-row-count/62401178#62401178)

Comment: @Dy.Lee, the solution you showed uses ActiveSheet. I'm trying to select the range from the table. Doesn't it matter?

Comment: Wen you paste a discontinue range (a filtered one), no need of visible cells range rows count is necessary. If needed, counting the range areas total rows will do the trick. What is happening when you paste the visible cells in another sheet? No matter it is there another table or not... Do you receive an error? Does the discontinue range is pasted discontinue, too? Does the range to be copied has merge cells?

Comment: @FaneDuru, no. I don't get any errors at all. I get empty rows at after the pasted values.

Comment: But what would you like to have after the pasted values, if your table has more rows then the pasted range? This is a normal behavior. Your belief about the issue is  not a correct one. Your `.Resize` part of the code does not do anything in terms of copying. You copy the range in one cell ( `Cells(1, 1)`) independent of preliminary resizing. If you want to delete the empty rows, you must add to your code a part to delete the empty rows...