# Excel vba Filtered table BodyRange incorrect SpecialCells

Tags: excel, vba, range, filtering

I have a table which I filter with a vba command:

```
tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=*" & Left(street, 3) & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
```

It's a *contains* filter, BodyRange (check visually) should count 7 rows, but with this

```
tbl.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

I only retrieve less just 4 of them, it's behaving like the BodyRange.SpecialCells capture from the filter only the values **beginning** with the filter value but not the ones containing it (if my filtered column street are "pilsudzki" "al. pilsudzki" "al. gen pilsudzki" BodyRange will skip all the "al. pilsudzki" etc... and give me only the "pilsudzki" i.e the one beginning with "*pils**")

to get around this I must use this trick instead:

```
Set rnTble = Sheet1.Range("K2:K150000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each cll In rnTble.Cells
Me.ListBox2.AddItem cll.Value
If cll.Value = "" Then Exit For
Next
```

then and only then I capture all the filtered value containing "*pils*"

Any ideas why is it that way?

Comment: Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400102/filtered-row-count/62401178#62401178).  Since the area is separated by discontinuity of data, the area must be used.

Answer (score 1):

The filtered part is the data divided into several areas. Because they are separated, you need to use areas.

```
For Each rng In rngTble.Areas
    For Each cll In rng
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem cll.Value
    Next cll
Next rng
```

### No filter

[image]

### filtered state

[image]

Comment: You're right - I have Areas count 2 in which one area (Item 1) has 4 rows and the other 3 rows. Don't know why but when I first worked with this area object I couldn't achieve the expected result... now it's okay. The area it's a classical topic with filtering. Neverthless thank you very much